# Load balancer, sockets and java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, tcp, load-balancing

I've got a project to work on and I need to build some client - server applications where I can send messages and whatever, in Java. One goal of the project is to deal with failover. When a client is connect to a server and the server dies, it automatically connects to the backup server. What I want to do is not required but I want to implement a load balancer so multiple clients get connected to the prefered server.

The connection between a client and the server must be with TCP sockets.

This is a schematic of the network architecture:
[image]

1. client connects to the load balancer (udp or tcp, I don't know the
   best one for this situation).
2. load balancer decides the which server should that client connect (the most empty one)
3. the client creates a TCP connection with the specified server

**My question is:**

How should the load balancer work to get a client to connect to specific server? Send information of the server (ip, port) to the client and the clients creates another socket with the new ip? (blue line).

Or is there a way for the load balancer to connect those two end points (server #1 <-> client #1), without having to send information to the client?

PS: I'm asking you because it seems unnecessary for each client to have to create 2 sockets to get connect to the server (first socket black line, second socket blue line)

Comment: This design decision depends on your requirements. Having the balancer route messages and data may make him a bottleneck and hinder scalability.

Comment: I want the load balancer to not act like a proxy, so each client directly connects to a specific server

Answer (score 1):

i think after the client sends information to the load balancer,its best if the load balancer sends that information to the server which it decides instead of sending something back to client and client connecting again to server

Comment: Depends on application ... If the Balancer would have to route large amounts of data through its network stack, then it could be more appropriate to just provide an address.

Comment: @KaushikSivakumar So you're saying after the load balancer decides which server to use, that server makes the connection to the client (and not client -> server)?